# QInputDialog does not return just text

Tags: python, pyqt

This is my code:

```
itemnum = QInputDialog.getText(self, "Recall - Item", "Item No.", QLineEdit.Normal, "")
print itemnum
```

It returns `(PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'aa'), True)`. How do i get just the text `"aa"`? Is the only solution to manipulate the string?

Comment: `print str(itemnum[0])`

Comment: Thank you @A.Rodas.. that just did it..

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from PyQt4.QtCore import QString
>>> s = QString('Test')
>>> s
    PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'Test')
>>> str(s)
    'Test'
```